# Accessing Text From Custom Component Without Using <cq:text>

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I have a custom component that contains two distinct text dialog tabs, text1 and text2. Normally, you output using `<cq:text property="text" tagClass="text" />`, but I need to determine if text2 contains content before outputting. So I'm trying to assign it to a local variable first.

```
<%
 String text2 = properties.get("text2", String.class);
%>
<cq:text property="text1" tagClass="text" />
<%
  if (text2 != null) {
    out.println(text2);
  }
%>
```

However, I get the error: **text2 cannot be resolved**

Am I missing some type of reference to this variable? Or can par-based text variables not be locally referenced like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `properties.get()` is a default value, not a class.  So try this:

```
<%
 String text2 = properties.get("text2", "");
%>
```

Comment: I've tried a version of your code in my environment and it works for me.  Could it be that your code actually has a closing brace between the definition of `text2` and its use?

Comment: You were right, I had the declaration inside an `if` statement by accident. Thanks!

Comment: The second argument can actually be either default value or class. http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html

Answer (score 6):

Using what David suggests to set the variable text2,

```
<%
  String text2 = properties.get("text2", "");
%>
```

you will need to change your condition in your if statement as what you have will always be true.

Explained:

If the property exists text2 will get the string value of the property including an empty string or string of only whitespace. If the property does not exists you are setting text2 to a default of an empty string. In Java an empty string is not null, so the condition in your if statement will always be true. A better check would be:

```
<%
  if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotBlank(text2)) {
    out.println(text2);
  }
%>
```

This will only return true if text2 is not null is not an empty string or a string with only white space chars. org.apache.commons.lang3 is provided in CQ5.

Comment: I actually did `if (text2.length() > 0)`, as checking for null doesn't work for text editor-based variables. Will your above function do the same?

Comment: The StringUtils.isNotBlank(String) checks null empty (length == 0) and  white space only strings ie("  "). It's a more robust check if you don't want to display an empty space.

Comment: Excellent knowledge to know!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<%
 String text2 = properties.get("text2", String.class);
%>
<cq:text property="text1" tagClass="text" />
<%
  if (text2 != null && !("".equals(text2.trim()))) {
%>
   <%= text2 %>
<%  
  }
%>
```

It just trims the text and checks if it's empty.  You can also remove the null check if you alter the second parameter as suggested above (and as described [here](http://aem.matelli.org/fetching-properties-from-dialogs/)).